# Dos append semi-random 3 digit number

Tags: cmd

Looking to run a windows command line that will take the file name and append a %random% three digit number onto the end. All with the understanding that its probably never truly random..

test_file.mp4 to test_file_582.mp4

Comment: What version of dos? Or do you really just mean Windows command-line (`cmd`)?

Comment: sorry, updated post for windows CMD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set /a num = %random% % 1000
ren test_file.mp4 test_file_%num%.mp4
```

Note it is possible for this to return the same pseudo-random number multiple times, so you may want to test existence of the new file before potentially clobbering something that already exists.

It also won't be padded out to three digits (i.e. you can have `test_file_1.mp4` as a result). I'll leave this as an exercise for the reader for now.